# How to pass Android post request response to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-webview

I created a webview on android studio and want to place the android post request response inside textarea on webiview . The post request is working correctly and i receive data from server but my Javascript function inside webview never get called to populate the textarea. Could an expert look at my code and show me how to fix it.Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links to open in the WebViewinstead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        new PostClass().execute();
    }


    private class PostClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            final TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postOutput);

            try {

                 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new Builder().permitAll().build());

                 HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://myownapi.com/api").openConnection();
                 myURLConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
                 myURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                 myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                 myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
                 myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                 myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                 myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                 myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
                 myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("API_KEY", "12345_ABC_MNO_12345678_123ABC");

                 myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                 myURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-length", "");



                 OutputStream os = myURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                 os.close();

                 myURLConnection.connect();

                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                 System.out.println(sb);
                 String line;

                 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                     sb.append(line);
                 }
                 in.close();

                 outputView.setText(sb.toString());
                 //outputView.setText("finished");
                 mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyFunction(" + sb.toString() + ")");
                 //mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyFunction()");



            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

html code inside webview:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function MyFunction(myVar)
        {
          //var myVar = 'test data';
          var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myArea');
          myTextArea.innerHTML += myVar;

        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<br>
<textarea id="myArea" rows="30" cols="40"></textarea>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello there you are missing quotes in

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyFunction(" + sb.toString() + ")");
```

Right now you what you call is this

> MyFunction(string)

instead this should be

> MyFunction('string')

So instead of passing a string you are trying to pass the variable like an object.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyFunction('" + sb.toString() + "')");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply .I tried that but nothing is placed on textarea. I even tried mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyFunction()"); with default value for myVar= in javascript and nothing placed on textarea! do you think placing webview inside onCreate is the problem ?